# nhibernate component mapping

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Account entity have Terms component which should be component.

```
Account.cs 
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public Terms Terms {get; set;}
...

Terms.cs
public string TermsText {get;set;}
public DateTime Created {get; set;}
```

Now I tried to mapp based on [this example](http://lycog.com/programming/nhibernate-32-mapping-code-component-mapping/) (by code)

```
AccountMap.cs
...
Component(p => p.Terms, TermsMap.Mapping());

TermsMap.cs
public class TermsMap
{
    public static Action<IComponentMapper<Terms>> Mapping()
    {
        return c =>
        {
            c.Property(p => p.TermsText);
            c.Property(p => p.Created);
        };
    }
}
```

> **NhibernateMappingException: Could not determine type for Terms**

What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You should post your whole mapping classes, as well as table definitions. A typo between CreateDate and Created ?
BTW : you should avoid giving your properties the same name as your classes (it would help knowing which 'Terms' the error message refers to)